# Show the current username in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, mysqlcommand, mysql-command-line-client

I would like to know if there's a way for a mysql query to return the username of the user that issues the query.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Try the `CURRENT_USER()` function.  This returns the username that MySQL used to authenticate your client connection.  It is this username that determines your privileges.

This may be different from the username that was sent to MySQL by the client (for example, MySQL might use an anonymous account to authenticate your client, even though you sent a username).  If you want the username the client sent to MySQL when connecting use the `USER()` function instead.

The value indicates the user name you specified when connecting to the server, and the client host from which you connected. The value can be different from that of CURRENT_USER().

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user

Comment: Thank you for your answer, if I'm reading this correctly, the advantage of using CURRENT_USER() instead of USER() is that CURRENT_USER() will only return authenticated users?

Comment: Basically, the client may specify a user to use for authentication--but that specific user may not have grant rights on a table.  Yet, access may still be granted because of anonymous rights on the table. This function returns the user in the grant rights that was used to authenticate the user (maybe anonymous) rather than the user specified by the client.  There's a good example in the docs there.

Comment: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CURRENT_USER()' at line 1`

Comment: Did you remember the SELECT in your query, ie: SELECT CURRENT_USER();  Post your query.

Comment: I tried this to test and `CURRENT_USER()` was not correct for the question "Is there a way to know _*your*_ current username in mysql?".  The answer was "USER()", which "Returns the current MySQL user" (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_user). You should update your answer to be more complete, it's way too short.

Answer (score 112):

Try to run either

```
SELECT USER();
```

or

```
SELECT CURRENT_USER();
```

It can sometimes be different, [USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_user) will return by which login you attempted to authenticate and [CURRENT_USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) will return how you were actually allowed to authenticate.

Answer (score 20):

Use this query:

```
SELECT USER();
```

Or

```
SELECT CURRENT_USER;
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use:

```
SELECT USER();
```

or

```
SELECT CURRENT_USER();
```

See more here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user

Answer (score 3):

to print the current user who is using the database

```
select user();
```

or

```
select current_user();
```

Comment: I don't like much your answer, not only it do not add anything new to what was previously answered, but your answer miss the most important part: the difference between those two functions.

Comment: *Within a stored program or view, CURRENT_USER() returns the account for the user who defined the object (as given by its DEFINER value) unless defined with the SQL SECURITY INVOKER characteristic. In the latter case, CURRENT_USER() returns the object's invoker.

Triggers and events have no option to define the SQL SECURITY characteristic, so for these objects, CURRENT_USER() returns the account for the user who defined the object. To return the invoker, use USER() or SESSION_USER().* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html

Comment: no one has time to read all history of those functions, and no one asked your explanation about those functions, the main question was how to find a user name in mysql, he didnt ask wat the differences of those two statements. and there is nothing to add new to the existing answerr, cause its the only answer, by answering it gains confidence to the user that this is the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the current user name with CURRENT_USER() function in MySQL.

for Ex:
 `SELECT CURRENT_USER();`

But `CURRENT_USER()` will not always return the logged in user. So in case you want to have the logged in user, then use `SESSION_USER()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use : 
mysql> select user,host from mysql.user;

```
+---------------+-------------------------------+
| user          | host                          |
+---------------+-------------------------------+
| fkernel       | %                             |
| nagios        | %                             |
| readonly      | %                             |
| replicant     | %                             |
| reporting     | %                             |
| reporting_ro  | %                             |
| nagios        | xx.xx.xx.xx                 |
| haproxy_root  | xx.xx.xx.xx
| root          | 127.0.0.1                     |
| nagios        | localhost                     |
| root          | localhost                     |
+---------------+-------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed such a feature and i used CURRENT_USER() but that gave me the Global Admin user which happens to be same for every query even if i changed the query username when connecting to the database.
Obviously that is useless in the use case i was looking for.
Then I used USER() and it gave me the username of the connection string that initiated the query.
if i understood the question, this is what the person wanted in plain language. In my case, i used it in a trigger to track changes made to rows in a transaction table.

Answer (score 0):

You can show the current user with [CURRENT_USER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user), [CURRENT_USER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) or [USER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_user) as shown below:

```sql
SELECT CURRENT_USER();
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT CURRENT_USER;
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT USER();
```

Be careful, `USER` doesn't exit so it gets error as shown below:

```sql
SELECT USER;
```

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'USER' in 'field list'

Now, the difference between `CURRENT_USER()` or `CURRENT_USER` and `USER()` is:

- `CURRENT_USER()` or `CURRENT_USER` returns the current user's name and the host.
- `USER()` returns the current user's name but returns the host from which you connect.

For example, you create the user `john` with `%` which means **any host** as shown below:

```sql
CREATE USER 'john'@'%';
```

Then, you log in with the user `john` from the server where MySQL is running (localhost) as shown below:

```
mysql -u john
```

Then, `CURRENT_USER()` or `CURRENT_USER` returns the current user's name and the host as shown below:

```sql
mysql> SELECT CURRENT_USER(); 
+----------------+
| CURRENT_USER() |
+----------------+
| john@%         |
+----------------+
```

Or:

```sql
mysql> SELECT CURRENT_USER;
+--------------+
| CURRENT_USER |
+--------------+
| john@%       |
+--------------+
```

Then, `USER()` returns the current user's name but returns the host from which you connect.

```sql
mysql> SELECT USER();
+----------------+
| USER()         |
+----------------+
| john@localhost |
+----------------+
```