# When saving product, send to MySql the admin user name

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I want to keep inventory logs. So I created in MySql a table `cataloginventory_stock_item_log`, which is updated by `triggers` to capture the qty `BEFORE UPDATE` and `AFTER UPDATE` from table `cataloginventory_stock_item`. So later I can run a report with the qty additions or subtractions.

My question is, I also want to capture the admin username (or email) so I know what user made the change to the quantity.

Is there a way the php files would pass to MySql the admin username out of the box? If not, what php files will have to be modified to accomplish this?

Below is the AFTER trigger I have used, I need to populate field by_user with the then current logged in @adminUser

```
CREATE TRIGGER qty_log_after_update
AFTER UPDATE
   ON cataloginventory_stock_item FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
   INSERT INTO cataloginventory_stock_item_log
   set
   type = 'after',
   product_id = old.product_id,
     qty_before = new.qty,
     qty_changed = (new.qty-old.qty),
     created_at = now(),
     by_user = @adminUser;

END;
```

Joell

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350275/is-there-a-way-to-know-your-current-username-in-mysql

Comment: Doesn't help. I need the Magento admin username who commits the change, not MySql user.

Comment: I'm not aware that you could do this in MySQL (as it's triggered based on MySQL events, nothing to do with the code running it from PHP).  You could look at creating a Magento extension that observes `cataloginventory_stock_item_save_commit_after` and does your insert instead of using the trigger?

Comment: Infact, http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25207/detect-inventory-change might be exactly what you're looking for?

Comment: @Douglas, thanks for the ref. However, from what I've tested the trigger IS working as expected, deducting qty when an order is placed, returning qty when cancelled, and changes qty on product save. My only concern is how to get the admin user name...passed to MySql so the trigger can record it.

Comment: @joell as suggested, there is no way to pass this into the trigger, as it has no relation to the code executing it